# Single Configuration Activity for multiple Homescreen Widgets

Tags: android

I have one Configuration Activity for different Hoomescreen Widgets for my Android App.

I get the WidgetId in the Configuration Activity like this:

```
widgetid = extras.getInt(
       AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, 
       AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

But later in the code I want to know which WidgetProvider class has called the Configuration Activity. How can i do this?

**P.S.**

I've found the answer:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(widgetid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [AppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetManager.html#getAppWidgetInfo(int)) as in

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
AppWidgetProviderInfo appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetInfo(widgetid);
```